# jQuery animation. How to make it restart with every carousel slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the Jquery code being used to animate a few images, but i would like to remove the following line from the code

jQuery('.banner_underlay').removeAttr('style');

and then get the animation to replay with every carousel slide. My jquery code below. Can anyone help?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.cycle-slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        after: on_after
    });
});

function on_after()
{
    jQuery('.banner_underlay').animate({
        left: '+=1000',
    }, 1050, function () {
        jQuery('.banner_underlay').removeAttr('style');
    });
    jQuery('.banner_overlay').animate({
        right: '+=2000',
    }, 1050, function () {
        jQuery('.banner_overlay').removeAttr('style');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger/set up an [event](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) each time the carousel slides. Set up a listener to call on_after(), or whatever animation you want to restart, every time that event is triggered.

Comment: Silly question, but how do i go abouts doing that? jQuery is not my strong  point. Thanks